# How to make a map from text file and set background of it as country in matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping, rasterizing, colormap

I want to make color map from text file which contains three columns( 1st is latitude, 2nd is longitude, 3rd is temperature). I have accessed to this code which reading and creating color map from text file (1-1000.text)

```
fid = fopen('1-1000.txt');
 C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f')
 fclose(fid);
 f = {'lat', 'long', 'temp'}
 S = cell2struct(C,f,2);

 N = 1000;
 [Xi, Yi] = meshgrid(linspace(60,80,N),linspace(20,40,N));
 Ci = griddata(S.long, S.lat, S.temp, Xi, Yi);
 colormap ('hot')
 imagesc(linspace(60,80,N),linspace(20,40,N),Ci);
 xlabel('Longitude');
 ylabel('Latitude');
 colorbar
```

I have shapefile of Pakistan(my data is of pakistan) and i want to show this color map variation over the pakistan. But have no idea how to set the background of the color map. For the shake i have attached with this post output of the maps which i required. Please help to resolve my question and thanks in advance for this kind assistance
M.Usman Saleem

This the data

```
Lat      long    temp
27.5    62.5    0
27.5    63.5    0
27.5    64.5    0
28.5    60.5    0
28.5    61.5    0
28.5    62.5    0
28.5    63.5    0
28.5    64.5    0
28.5    65.5    0
29.5    60.5    0
29.5    62.5    0
29.5    63.5    0
29.5    64.5    0
29.5    65.5    0
29.5    68.5    0
29.5    69.5    0
30.5    60.5    0
30.5    62.5    0
30.5    63.5    0
30.5    64.5    0
30.5    65.5    0
30.5    66.5    0
31.5    60.5    0
31.5    63.5    0
31.5    64.5    0
33.5    60.5    0
35.5    74.5    0
35.5    75.5    0
36.5    71.5    0
37.5    72.5    0
37.5    75.5    0
37.5    77.5    0
37.5    78.5    0
38.5    76.5    0
25.5    77.5    228.5
27.5    66.5    106.8
23.5    76.5    192.7
24.5    77.5    188.3
27.5    71.5    26
35.5    61.5    262.4
32.5    60.5    83.6
37.5    60.5    10.7
36.5    61.5    9
36.5    66.5    45.8
36.5    68.5    43.9
24.5    60.5    178.3
23.5    64.5    187.8
31.5    62.5    47.1
26.5    63.5    250.9
22.5    64.5    209.4
23.5    61.5    181.9
23.5    65.5    185
23.5    62.5    172.5
22.5    62.5    179.9
22.5    63.5    184.2
24.5    62.5    173.3
24.5    63.5    178
23.5    63.5    180.4
22.5    65.5    192.8
24.5    64.5    177.2
24.5    65.5    162.7
22.5    61.5    175.9
22.5    66.5    207.61
24.5    61.5    183.6
23.5    66.5    163.2
23.5    60.5    180.4
23.5    67.5    200.4
22.5    67.5    194.6
22.5    60.5    166.2
24.5    66.5    182
25.5    60.5    179.8
23.5    68.5    205.8
22.5    68.5    198.1
37.5    69.5    417
25.5    66.5    43.9
31.5    61.5    159.7
24.5    68.5    11.9
38.5    62.5    74.6
38.5    60.5    63.5
38.5    61.5    114
37.5    61.5    113.4
38.5    64.5    110.7
38.5    63.5    92.8
37.5    63.5    136.1
37.5    64.5    118
37.5    62.5    98.6
38.5    65.5    77.8
37.5    65.5    93.5
37.5    67.5    74.1
37.5    68.5    87.9
36.5    65.5    168.8
37.5    66.5    168.1
36.5    67.5    174.5
38.5    66.5    229.8
25.5    75.5    21.5
28.5    74.5    267.6
28.5    72.5    287.5
28.5    73.5    278
35.5    63.5    281.8
30.5    71.5    2.1
28.5    71.5    307.4
29.5    73.5    237.6
34.5    62.5    202.9
31.5    71.5    202
32.5    71.5    139.6
31.5    73.5    117.6
28.5    68.5    238.9
30.5    72.5    167.3
31.5    72.5    133.1
29.5    72.5    220.8
32.5    73.5    103.7
33.5    72.5    68
28.5    75.5    389.1
35.5    60.5    201.6
29.5    74.5    230.3
28.5    69.5    199.5
32.5    74.5    109.4
31.5    74.5    93.7
38.5    77.5    227.5
27.5    72.5    23.6
29.5    71.5    223.5
30.5    73.5    171.8
34.5    60.5    31.3
29.5    75.5    197.6
30.5    75.5    121.7
27.5    68.5    255.7
33.5    71.5    94.4
28.5    70.5    252.7
30.5    74.5    119
26.5    70.5    537
27.5    70.5    184.5
23.5    70.5    519.5
29.5    70.5    212.6
38.5    78.5    75.3
23.5    69.5    464.5
28.5    76.5    228.5
34.5    61.5    56.5
26.5    69.5    419.2
27.5    77.5    210.9
31.5    70.5    154
25.5    68.5    322.4
27.5    78.5    180.2
31.5    75.5    111.2
23.5    71.5    487.1
26.5    71.5    405
24.5    71.5    442.2
34.5    71.5    101.4
28.5    78.5    153
24.5    70.5    306.6
28.5    77.5    145.9
25.5    71.5    460.1
25.5    70.5    406.4
27.5    69.5    344.8
25.5    69.5    352.8
26.5    68.5    313.1
26.5    77.5    201.6
27.5    73.5    144.2
30.5    76.5    130.7
29.5    76.5    149
33.5    73.5    67.1
22.5    70.5    440.6
22.5    69.5    295.7
22.5    71.5    440.3
25.5    67.5    230.7
29.5    77.5    150.7
24.5    69.5    394.8
22.5    72.5    409.2
26.5    72.5    272
23.5    72.5    477.2
26.5    67.5    141.9
24.5    72.5    376.8
26.5    76.5    158.8
29.5    78.5    152.2
25.5    72.5    331.3
30.5    70.5    89.8
27.5    74.5    384.6
23.5    73.5    372.3
33.5    61.5    14.3
26.5    73.5    230.3
27.5    76.5    160.2
26.5    78.5    113
25.5    78.5    311.7
30.5    77.5    51
25.5    74.5    141.1
26.5    74.5    172.7
27.5    67.5    97.9
22.5    74.5    292.9
23.5    78.5    88
31.5    76.5    85.2
24.5    73.5    142.1
26.5    75.5    115.9
27.5    75.5    201.5
25.5    76.5    145
25.5    73.5    203.2
24.5    74.5    214.4
23.5    74.5    269.9
24.5    76.5    192
24.5    75.5    199.5
27.5    60.5    29.4
22.5    76.5    87.9
24.5    78.5    184.6
28.5    67.5    22
22.5    73.5    496.8
23.5    75.5    218.8
31.5    65.5    17.6
22.5    77.5    216.6
23.5    77.5    167.3
26.5    60.5    42.3
26.5    65.5    14.9
22.5    78.5    119.4
31.5    66.5    150.7
34.5    67.5    3386.3
32.5    63.5    0
36.5    63.5    0
36.5    64.5    0
35.5    62.5    0
36.5    62.5    0
36.5    60.5    0
36.5    72.5    0
36.5    73.5    0
38.5    72.5    0
36.5    74.5    0
37.5    73.5    0
38.5    73.5    0
37.5    74.5    0
34.5    76.5    0
30.5    61.5    0
25.5    61.5    0
33.5    76.5    0
35.5    76.5    0
25.5    65.5    0
34.5    77.5    0
25.5    62.5    0
25.5    64.5    0
24.5    67.5    0
31.5    78.5    0
25.5    63.5    0
36.5    78.5    0
36.5    75.5    0
36.5    76.5    0
33.5    77.5    0
36.5    77.5    0
26.5    61.5    0
26.5    62.5    0
32.5    77.5    0
34.5    78.5    0
33.5    78.5    0
32.5    78.5    0
32.5    72.5    0
35.5    77.5    0
35.5    78.5    0
22.5    75.5    0
27.5    61.5    0
34.5    63.5    0
38.5    68.5    0
38.5    69.5    0
38.5    67.5    0
36.5    69.5    0
32.5    61.5    0
38.5    70.5    0
37.5    70.5    0
35.5    64.5    0
33.5    70.5    0
32.5    75.5    0
33.5    62.5    0
36.5    70.5    0
32.5    65.5    0
35.5    66.5    0
29.5    67.5    0
35.5    68.5    0
37.5    76.5    0
33.5    74.5    0
34.5    73.5    0
38.5    75.5    0
35.5    65.5    0
35.5    69.5    0
31.5    69.5    0
27.5    65.5    0
34.5    70.5    0
29.5    66.5    0
32.5    76.5    0
28.5    66.5    0
32.5    69.5    0
32.5    66.5    0
33.5    65.5    0
34.5    69.5    0
35.5    67.5    0
33.5    63.5    0
32.5    67.5    0
35.5    71.5    0
31.5    68.5    0
33.5    75.5    0
31.5    67.5    0
31.5    77.5    0
34.5    65.5    0
30.5    67.5    0
32.5    68.5    0
33.5    69.5    0
33.5    66.5    0
34.5    64.5    0
35.5    72.5    0
32.5    64.5    0
33.5    67.5    0
33.5    68.5    0
34.5    68.5    0
34.5    74.5    0
32.5    70.5    0
37.5    71.5    0
34.5    66.5    0
35.5    70.5    0
35.5    73.5    0
34.5    75.5    0
34.5    72.5    0
32.5    62.5    0
38.5    74.5    0
38.5    71.5    0
26.5    64.5    0
26.5    66.5    0
30.5    69.5    0
33.5    64.5    0
29.5    61.5    0
30.5    68.5    0
30.5    78.5    0
```

& this is the image (shape file here not uploading that why i share image here)
[image]

& what i want is shown one of the maps shown below
[image]

Comment: Can you post some example data that shows in what way this is different than the duplicate question? AFAIK, points outside the `griddata` should get `NaN` values.

Comment: @Shai see my edited question again. I have upload map there and solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: no solution of problem yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = 1000;
[Xi, Yi] = meshgrid(linspace(37,42,N),linspace(-6.9,2.5,N));
Ci = griddata(A(:,2), A(:,1), A(:,3), Xi, Yi);
colormap ('hot')
imagesc(linspace(37,42,N),linspace(-6.9,2.5,N),Ci);
xlabel('Longitude');
ylabel('Latitude');
colorbar
```